# Joomla 3.x custom component view is shown in wrong template design

Tags: templates, joomla, routes, custom-component

I am developing a custom component. In this component I need Joomla's Redirect with its inbuilt function `JRoute` for example:

```
JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_customcomponent&view=registration');
```

I have a menu item, which is linked to the URL above and has an alias with the name **registration**. Furthermore I set a special template for this view. If I call the link http://www.mywebsite.com/registration => the view will be opened with the right design (special template).

If I access it on a direct way http://www.mywebsite.com/index.php?option=com_customcomponent&view=registration or inside my component with `JRoute`, the view will be shown with the wrong template (it will be show with the Standard Template and not the special template).

What could be wrong here?

Comment: This question is about Joomla specific implementation details and may get more answers on [the Joomla Q&A StackExhange site](http://joomla.stackexchange.com)

Comment: I did an module override of the mod_login module. And there I have to route the register link, to my special developed register view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is necessary to put the Menu Item in the link.

JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_customcomponent&view=registration&Itemid=xx')